# Spring Thymleaf internationalization does't getting messages from resources

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf

I have Spring web project.I want to implement internationalization with ThymLeaf.
I have added messages file under resources. but i always get error on page like `??page.title_en_US??` or if pass `lang=en` in QueryString then it look like `??page.title_en??`.
when is fetch messages in Controller by using MessageResource its returning all messages that is defined in Properties file :`messageSource.getMessage("page.title",null,locale)`
My resource file structure is : 
                                 resources

```
                                       i18n/messages.properties
                                       i18n/messages_en.properties
```

Here is my Bean configuration:

```
    /**
 * This method is used for configure thymeleaf view resolver.
 * This view resolver have second priority.
 * */
private ViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    thymeleafViewResolver.setViewClass(ThymeleafView.class);
    thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());

    return thymeleafViewResolver;
}


/**
 * This method is used to configure template engine for thymeleaf.
 * */
private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

    return templateEngine;
}

/**
 * This method is used for configure the thymeleaf view configuration.
 * */
private SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    //ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    //ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");

    resolver.setOrder(2);
    return resolver;
}


@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return slr;
}


@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    // messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600); //refresh cache once per hour
    return messageSource;
}
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

Comment: Spring automatically fetch message property files directly under resources folder. Is there any different if you remove addResourceHandlers and messageSource bean definitions and move files directly under the resources folder?

Comment: My problem has been solved i have found the solution.
I have missed `@Bean` annotation on methods `templateResolver` and `templateEngine`.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved my problem. `@Bean` annotation was missed on `templateResolver` and `templateEngine`. and these methods should be `public` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Might missed the annotation of "@Configuration" in bean configuration class.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer but a comment